# pygame install without root

Tags: python, unix, opencv, pygame, simplecv

I'm on a university machine so I have no root access and I'm trying to use the drawing libraries from SimpleCV.

As it is I have pygame installed *without* font but the drawing functions appear to require that I have font available. With some googling I have found that sdl_font is the dependency and have compiled it into a folder in my home directory.

My question is:
How do I convince pygame to recognise that library's location when installing?

I've tried adding the lib directory under my sdl_font install directory to LD_LIBRARY_PATH to no avail.

Comment: There's a path to the SDL files in [Setup.in](https://bitbucket.org/pygame/pygame/src/0ca386dee6c1/Setup.in). Maybe try munging that?

Comment: I've actually figured it out:

I needed to set the environment variable "LOCALBASE" to contain the installation directory. I would answer myself but I'm not allowed to yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about trying pyglet? http://www.pyglet.org/

It has "No external dependencies or installation requirements."

Comment: Unfortunately I need pygame as a dependency and not as a choice.